# Input box putting margin to right in a table with full width

Tags: css, input, width, css-tables

When I try to put an input box in a table which has a width of 100%, it puts margin to right. I just want inputs to fit the table without expanding the table.

http://jsfiddle.net/aKznJ/1/

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
.fullWidth table {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
}
.fullWidth td, .fullWidth th{
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 3px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats how tables work, it calculates the width of each column based on how big the content is in relation to the other cells. The TextBox is larger than all the others cells text, so that column get more of the percentage.

You can add a fixed width for the cell, for example like so:

```
<td style="width:150px;">
    <input type="text"/>
</td>
```

[Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/jx9PE/)

---

OR if you want the cells to be evenly spread, you can add a percentage to the cells with CSS like so:

```
table tr td {
    width: 33%;
}
```

[Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/jx9PE/1/)

But keep in mind that this will apply to all tables, so if different tables have different number of columns then you would need to do different ones for each table, for example:

```
table.threecolumns tr td {
    width: 33%;
}

table.twocolumns tr td {
    width: 50%;
}
```

The HTML for this might look like the following:

```
<table class="threecolumns">
   ...
</table>
```

[Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/jx9PE/2/)

Comment: thanks for the information about how table works, solved now :)

Answer (score 0):

add a class to your `<td>`where your input is. And specify its width in CSS or directly you can specify in `<td>`

```
<td class="textStyle">
    <input type="text"/>
</td>
```

And CSS

```
.textStyle{
    width:100px;
}
```

**OR**

```
<td width=100px>
    <input type="text"/>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the input width to 100% should do the trick

```
input {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I dont think this is what the OP wants, I think the problem is the table column size, not that the text box doesn't fill it

Comment: He mentioned that the table should not expand. But indeed the column width must be given to prevent shrinking of the other columns.